# Eclipse complains "No symbol table is loaded" while elf file contains debug info

Tags: eclipse, gdb, stm32, symbol-table

I am working on an STM32 processor.
Using readelf -w, tons of debug information could be extracted from my elf file. A short piece of the output is shown below:

```
 <1><3faf>: Abbrev Number: 30 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <3fb0>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x24e): ITM_RxBuffer 
    <3fb4>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 19 
    <3fb5>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1742   
    <3fb7>   DW_AT_type        : <0x3f48>   
    <3fbb>   DW_AT_external    : 1  
    <3fbc>   DW_AT_declaration : 1
```

dwarfdump also confirms debug info is available in elf file.

I am using the following software packages:
Eclipse Juno
arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb
OpenOCD and JTAG key

After producing elf file, burn it into STM32 processor, and start the debug session in Eclipse.
JTAG could be started and stopped, so I guess OpenOCD deamon is fine. Breakpoint cannot be set due to the fact "No symbol table is loaded". One thing I noticed is among the "variable/breakponts/register/modules" window, the modules tab showing the elf file loaded contains followiing details:
Type: executable
symbols: not loaded
symbol file: BuildResult.elf

In debug configuration->Startup tab, check/uncheck "Load image/Load symbols" make no difference. I am wondering how eclipse loads elf file contained symbol info into the debug process?

Any suggestions, hints, are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you compile with -g and/or -Og?

Answer (score 0):

This mostly cause by the fact that your program does not compile with the debug information.
To fix this,

1. Turn off all the optimization (use optimize for debug if such an option exists)
2. Based on your toolchain and the compiler/debugger used, there will be further switches that needed to be enabled. One common one is `-ggdb` for gdb debug.

Furthermore, it is nice to know that
`-g` produces debugging information in native format (stabs, COFF, XCOFF, or DWARF 2).

`-ggdb` produces gdb-friendly debugging information

`-ggdb3` produces additional debugging information

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something having plugins for your hardware. I would suggest STM32CubeIDE not the DIY Eclipse IDE.

My guess is that you use generic `gdb` not `arm-none-eabi-gdb` and it never worked for me when I was trying to use multiarch `gdb` instead of dedicated one.